# Deserializing a collection of base class objects does not call inherited Converters

Tags: json.net, json-deserialization

My classes are more complicated than this but here's the jist:

```
public class BaseClass {}

[JsonConverter(typeof(DerivedClassJsonConverter)]
public class DerivedClass: BaseClass {}

public class DerivedClassJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(DerivedClass) || objectType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(DerivedClass));
    }
    
    // implementations both ReadJson() and WriteJson()
}

[JsonConverter(typeof(BaseClassListJsonConverter)]
public class BaseClassList
{
    private List<BaseClass> list;
}
```

DerivedClassJsonConverter's WriteJson() does get called if I serialize a collection of BaseClass like this:

```
// this is a snippet from BaseClassListJsonConverter.WriteJson() override
writer.WritePropertyName("list");
writer.WriteStartArray();
for (int i = 0; i < SOME_COUNT; i++)
{
    BaseClass bc = new DerivedClass();
    serializer.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto;
    serializer.Serialize(writer, bc, typeof(BaseClass));
}
writer.WriteEndArray();
```

However, DerivedClassJsonConverter's ReadJson() does not get called if I deserialize like this:

```
// this is a snippet from BaseClassListJsonConverter.ReadJson() override (assume reader is at the correct Token
serializer.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All;
List<BaseClass> baseClassList = (List<BaseClass>)serializer.Deserialize(reader, typeof(List<BaseClass>));
```

Is this not supported or am I doing something incorrectly?

Thank you for your time and help.